# C++ object model transformation?

Tags: c++, oop

I have 2 systems with 2 related but slightly different object models (one model has a class for contract relationships between partners, the other uses a different, but derived notion (and a different class)). I need to write a "mapper" that navigates the first model and produces an instances of the second model (there are containers, classes...). Is there a tool/library (preferably declarative?) that I could use to generate the mapper code?

Answer (score 1):

There is none that I'm aware of. Usually you write small wrapper modules using the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: Yes. I was thinking I could save a lot of work by having a declarative tool where I would just specify the transformation function and it would generate the code for me...

Answer (score 1):

There may be simpler ways, but one option is to use Boost::Serialization, which allows you to specify a serialization format for each object very compactly (if not strictly declaratively).

Then you could serialize one set of objects to XML, and use XSLT to convert them to the format of the other set of objects.  Then you deserialize the other set of objects.

If you specify the serialization of the two sets of objects properly, it might be possible to skip the whole conversion to XML/XSLT step.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll investigate that. Thanks!